# Telegram for android on C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, telegram, tdlib

Does anyone have a simple telegram client example written in C# that can be run on android?

- I found simple java example for android: https://github.com/androidmads/TelegramBotSample
- I found simple C# example for console application: https://github.com/tdlib/td

But I need a simple example that I can just download and run for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the things is even more complicated for C# android.
Steps that I currently made:

- Create .net android application using MAUI.
- Add TdLib, TdLibApi and TdLib.Native nuget packages
- -> On real android device creating new TdClient is failing with binding not found exception.
- Take android example from https://github.com/tdlib/td and try to build them
- -> It requires to install 10+ different packages and still failing with memory issue on compilation
- -> Search those files (libtdjni.so, libtdjson.so) on github.
- Put those files to proper libs folder (for android it is
- Check what methods are available in those .so files (In those that I found there were no method td_set_log_verbosity_level)

```
android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-nm -D ./libtdjni.so
```

- Take implementation of LinuxBinding from https://github.com/egramtel/tdsharp and copy it